# BufferedReader.readLine() pauses my application?

Tags: java

I am using this code:

```
while (true) {
    sendData("hi");
    System.out.println("Data sent!");
    BufferedReader inFromServer;
    try {
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        inFromServer = null;
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Recieved!"); //I see this de-bug message.
    try {
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence); //I do NOT see this de-bug message!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It successfully sends data to a server - And the server successfully sends data back:

```
public void run () {
    //handle the session using the socket (example)
    try {
        sendData("Hi");
        System.out.println("Data sent!"); //I see this de-bug message.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However for some reason, the application seems to pause at the inFromServer.readLine() method. I see the "Recieved!" de-bug message, but not the "FROM SERVER" de-bug message.

[image]

There are no errors at all. It just seems to hang there.

Why is it hanging, and how can I fix that?

Comment: One problem is that you're not breaking out of the `while(true)` loop

Comment: @imtheman "FROM SERVER" is in the loop, this is not the problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard True, it is not *the* problem, but it is *a* problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I've had a busy day, only just now got to look at this. The accepted answer works perfectly fine now. I am getting data from the server and receiving data. By the way, not breaking out of the while loop isn't an issue - The TCP client is ALWAYS going to be receiving new data until the application ends, meaning I don't ever want to break out of it anyway.

Comment: @Joehot200 I'm not sure what you mean by "the accepted answer works perfectly fine now", as there is no accepted answers. But anyway, I'm glad to hear it works.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Sorry. I'm tired. I forgot to accept it. I've had a horribly long weekend with only 7 hours of sleep each day. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Joehot200 No problem at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this simply means that `inFromServer` does not receive any line.

Make sure you really send a line,

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Have a look at the `readLine` method :

```
String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer s = null;
    int startChar;

    synchronized (lock) {
        ensureOpen();
        boolean omitLF = ignoreLF || skipLF;

    bufferLoop:
        for (;;) {

            if (nextChar >= nChars)
                fill();
            if (nextChar >= nChars) { /* EOF */
                if (s != null && s.length() > 0)
                    return s.toString();
                else
                    return null;
            }
            boolean eol = false;
            char c = 0;
            int i;

            /* Skip a leftover '\n', if necessary */
            if (omitLF && (cb[nextChar] == '\n'))
                nextChar++;
            skipLF = false;
            omitLF = false;

        charLoop:
            for (i = nextChar; i < nChars; i++) {
                c = cb[i];
                if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
                    eol = true;
                    break charLoop;
                }
            }

            startChar = nextChar;
            nextChar = i;

            if (eol) {
                String str;
                if (s == null) {
                    str = new String(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                } else {
                    s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                    str = s.toString();
                }
                nextChar++;
                if (c == '\r') {
                    skipLF = true;
                }
                return str;
            }

            if (s == null)
                s = new StringBuffer(defaultExpectedLineLength);
            s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this one receive a boolean, but calling `readLine` simply call this one with `false` passed, unless on Linux.

Notice the `for(;;)` loop, which is an infinite loop.

Try concatening to the "line" sent from the server

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Comment: Probably your server needs to send back `sendData("Hi\n");`

Comment: Would be better to use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` see edit.

Comment: Adding \n at the end of each message has worked perfectly.
Quick question, is the \n counted in the .readLine() method? As in, if I were to process the string, would the \n be counted as part of it in my code?

Comment: @Joehot200 Yes, the \n is a part of the line. However, you should use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` instead as line terminaison are not the same on all systems. This will take care of that.